# AIR 2.5 to 3.2 upgrade fail, error 16824 and 16815

Tags: apache-flex, air

We just pushed an update to our application in production.
The initial version uses Air SDK 2.5 while we pushed a SDK 3.2. Upon detection of the new version and downloading the app, we have an error# 16824.

If the user uninstalls the 2.5 app, and installs manually the 3.2 one, the application works fine.

Any ideas?

------ edit

We had the update.xml with the 2.5 (wrong) naming space

`<update xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/framework/update/description/2.5">...`

But when replacing it with the 3.2 ns:

`<update xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/framework/update/description/3.2">...`

the app doesn't download and I get an error 16815.

There is an answer [there](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4510437) but we already double-checked that the updater swc are the right ones i.e. from SDK3.2.

Error 16815 is "Invalid update descriptor (unknown descriptor version)."
See reference [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/air/update/ApplicationUpdaterUI.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [ADOBE AIR : Error #16824 : Version mismatch while trying to auto update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748610/adobe-air-error-16824-version-mismatch-while-trying-to-auto-update)

Comment: flextras, thanks for the pointer, but I am past the schema change that occurred at 2.5. My problem is between 2.5 and 3.2 (or higher).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RAGE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!

For error 16815, check the following file in the sdk folder:
`<sdk>\frameworks\projects\air\ApplicationUpdater\src\ApplicationUpdater\air\update\descriptors\UpdateDescriptor.as` function `isKnownVersion`

The only name spaces authorized are 1.0 and 2.5.

I have checked for SDK 3.2 and 3.4, they all have the same restrictions.
Step to fix:

1. Create a package air.update.descriptors in your src folder
2. Copy the UpdateDescriptor.as into this package
3. Add the following blocks into UpdateDescriptor.as

`public static const NAMESPACE_UPDATE_3_2:Namespace = new Namespace("http://ns.adobe.com/air/framework/update/description/3.2");`

and
`case NAMESPACE_UPDATE_3_2.uri:`

You now have allowed your favorite sdk!